# Fit QTextEdit size to text size pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit

I try to make the QTextEdit change its width value to the length of the text that is entered in it.

But the problem is that when using the resize property it does not do anything and does not change the size

I am obeying the length of the current word in the list and that value is the one I try to send as a property width() to the QTextEdit

to get something like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QWidget,QVBoxLayout,QApplication,QTextEdit,QPushButton,QScrollArea

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.lista = ["one","two","abcdefghijklmn","zxyw","xyxyxyxyx"]

        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)

        self.area = QScrollArea(self)
        self.area.resize(400,300)
        self.area.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.area.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.plain  =QTextEdit(self)
        self.plain.move(0,305)
        self.plain.resize(400,50)

        self.boton = QPushButton(self)
        self.boton.move(0,360)
        self.boton.setText("Press")

        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.Test)

    def Test(self):
        for i in self.lista:
            longitud = len(i)*6.3
            print(longitud)
            self.text = QTextEdit(self)
            self.text.document().setPlainText(i)
            self.text.setReadOnly(True)
            self.text.resize(longitud,10)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.text)

app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
m.resize(600,400)
app.exec()
```

**Actually what I need is that the QTextEdit that are created to fill the QScrollArea conform to the size of the length of text characters**

[image]

This is the result I get but what I need is that the QTextEdit have the width() to where the line ends

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my attempt to solve this problem using font metrics to measure the size of the text box contents:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QFontMetrics
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QTextEdit, QPushButton, QScrollArea


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.lista = ["one", "two", "abcdefghijklmn", "zxyw", "xyxyxyxyx"]

        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)

        self.area = QScrollArea(self)
        self.area.resize(400,300)
        self.area.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.area.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.plain = QTextEdit(self)
        self.plain.move(0,305)
        self.plain.resize(400,50)

        self.boton = QPushButton(self)
        self.boton.move(0,360)
        self.boton.setText("Press")

        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.Test)

    def Test(self):
        for i in self.lista:
            text = QTextEdit(self)
            text.document().setPlainText(i)

            font = text.document().defaultFont()
            fontMetrics = QFontMetrics(font)
            textSize = fontMetrics.size(0, text.toPlainText())

            w = textSize.width() + 10
            h = textSize.height() + 10
            text.setMinimumSize(w, h)
            text.setMaximumSize(w, h)
            text.resize(w, h)

            text.setReadOnly(True)

            self.layout.addWidget(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = Main()
    m.show()
    m.resize(600, 400)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Result:

[image: Result]